# Why doesn't C code work properly in __attribute__((naked)) functions?

Tags: c, arm

I am working on an ARM CORTEX microcontroller and have written a function 'x' for context switching of a thread.

This function included all __asm() calls and hence I used `__attribute__((naked))`.

After some time, when I called a function f(), the entire function x() wasn't being called at all. Hence no context switch happened.

Why is this happening? Should I not use `__attribute__((naked))` ?

Code:

**In file1.c**

```
__attribute__((naked)) void SysTick_Handler(void){

    tick_increment();

    // context switch inline assembly code
}
```

**In file2.c**

```
volatile uint32_t tick_cnt;
volatile uint32_t tick_freq = 1;

void tick_increment(void){

    tick_cnt += tick_freq;

}
```

Since I am calling tick_increment() inside this SysTick Handler function, it never gets called when the CVR hits 0.

Note: SysTick_Handler gets called automatically when the CVR hits 0.

Comment: why don't you show the broken code and explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: It looks like your function is supposed to be called from an interrupt handler. So there might be other reasons it is not being called, such as that the interrupt is not being fired.

Comment: Are you *sure* your code works when you remove the `naked` attribute?  I just [tried it](https://godbolt.org/z/WKeKWbqz7) on Godbolt and that shouldn't affect the code at all, in both cases your SysTick_Handler is just a simple branch instruction to the function it calls.   I suspect this problem has nothing to do with `naked` and you should start troubleshooting anew, and post a new question with a [mcve] when you can.

Comment: BTW, `tick_increment` is definitely not an "__asm() call"...

Comment: @DavidGrayson Yes it worked perfectly fine when I removed the naked attribute. I tried making the variables extern etc.. but of no use.

Comment: @EugeneSh. tick_increment is the function f() i am taking about in the question.

Comment: @YuvrajSakshith  That is very strange.  What version of GCC are you using and what is the full command you use to compile `file1.c` (which contains the `naked` attribute)?  Did you really show us the full code you are actually testing in your question above or is this just a rough sketch based on your memory of what the code might be?

Comment: Calling a C function in a naked function is not something that is guaranteed to work. Anyway, you should examine the generated assembly and see what your code is compiling into. You should show more of your code though, there might be additional things that are not allowed in naked functions. Or your assembly might clobber some registers that are supposed to be callee-saved. When using this attribute, you should know *exactly* what you are doing.

Comment: "naked" tells the compiler not to insert the code that it usually inserts in functions which are required to make them work properly. So agree with "you should know exactly what you're doing"

Comment: This is a cortex-M CPU, that is an important fact.  There is no need to use 'naked' with a cortex-M.  With a Cortex-A, you might go `naked`.  The 'BSP' and linker files are probably handling 'SysTick_Handler()' so that it is placed as an entry in the vector table.  A standard return will resume the normal processing.  Note: that are various interrupt options for a Cortex-M.  Naked is most assuredly the wrong thing to do.  I suspect you get an issue with nested interrupts.  With 'naked' your function call might return from the interrupt; but it won't if something else gets put in LR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer is:**

`SysTick_Handler` is an interrupt handler and has to be defined without `__attribute__((naked))`.

**A bit longer answer:**

Each interrupt routine needs to store some registers before invoking interrupt handler and restore it just before returning from interrupt. The storing and restoring procedures are generated automatically by the compiler and surround user code inside every interrupt handler. When you define interrupt handler as `__attribute__((naked))` you get rid of these automatically generated code messing up the main program execution.

**Example of unexpected behaviour**

Let's have a look how `__attribute__((naked))` interrupt handler can mess up the main program.
For example, consider *one of the possible implementations* of `if (a == 0)` condition:

1. The value of the variable `a` is loaded from RAM into a register (let it be `r16`).
2. The value of `r16` register is compared with zero.
3. While comparing the value of the Status register is changing. Some bits in this register reflect the comparision result.
4. Branch instruction examine the comparison result bit of the Status register and perfirm jump to one branch or another.

The condition hereby works right only if there are no unexpected changes of Status register between steps 2 and 4.

**A. Normal interrupt execution**

Main program starts execution of `if (a == 0)` condition:

1. `a` is loaded from RAM into `r16` register.
2. `r16` is compared with zero.
3. Status register updated.
   ---> *INTERRUPT IS HIT*
   a. Interrupt handler is executed.
   b. Save Status register to stack.
   c. Execute user code (suppose Status register is changed).
   d. Restore Status register from stack.
   e. Return from interrupt handler.
   <--- *INTERRUPT COMPLETED*
4. Branch instruction examine Status register (***from step 3***).

Everithing works well.

**B. Naked interrupt execution**

Main program starts execution of `if (a == 0)` condition:

1. `a` is loaded from RAM into `r16` register.
2. `r16` is compared with zero.
3. Status register updated.
   ---> *INTERRUPT IS HIT*
   a. Interrupt handler is executed.
   b. Execute user code (suppose Status register is changed).
   c. Return from interrupt handler.
   <--- *INTERRUPT COMPLETED*
4. Branch instruction examine Status register (***from step b***).

The value of examined Status register does not reflect the comparison done in step 2, the branch instruction could jump to the wrong branch.

This is just an example, real messing up can arise in many other ways with the `__attribute__((naked))` interrupt handlers.